# Differential cryptanalysis to ciphertext-only attacks on xxTEA

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, tea

In my IoT project, I use the xxTEA encryption algorithm to encrypt my data. I use the same encryption key for all my packets because I don't have the possibility to do a key exchange between Alice and Bob.

I want to know how many packets it would take to deduce my key. I looked on the document of Alex Biryukov named "*Differential cryptanalysis to ciphertext-only attacks*" (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBFb0055721.pdf) but I don't understand everything and can't find the calculation that gives me the result I'm looking for.

I send two packet per minute and I search to know how often do I have to change my key, before my encryption becomes insecure.

Comment: Where in that document is xxTEA mentioned at all?

Comment: Hello @PresidentJamesK.Polk, xxTEA isn't mentioned, but it's a cipher block encryption algorithm. So, I want to make the same calcul for xxTEA. Let me know if you have other questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Elias Yarrkov published a [Cryptanalysis of XXTEA (2010)](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Cryptanalysis-of-XXTEA-Yarrkov/ffbfd62de840f6ccf3dc4fbb920934d908d554bc) citing about $2^{59}$ queries and negligible work is required for a chosen-plaintext attack.